# Pac-Man Type Animation to Unity

Tags: modifiers, export, unity

I am making [Pac-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man) mouth close/open animation.
My goal is to bring it into Unity.

At first I made this combination of a sphere and a cube by using boolean modifier.
Then I changed the size of the cube and made shape keys animation.

[image]

It works well in Blender, but in Unity it doesn't work, because Unity doesn't understand the Boolean modifier.

[image]

As the next method, I tried to apply Boolean modifier in Blender and remove the cube.
Then the open-mouth is OK, but how can I close Pac-Man's mouth?????

[image]

**Q:** Basically is my approach wrong here? Or how can I close his mouth?

I am a new bee for Blender. I appreciate your any advice.

Comment: you can use shape keys but im also not sure will it work , modifiers will definitely not work because unity doesn't know what modifier is it.....

Comment: I have checked `Shape Keys` works well (handled as `Blend Shape`) on `Unity`. And `shape modifier` not. But I have no idea how to make packman-like mouth movement, without using `boolean modifier` on `Blender`.

Comment: There are shape keys in blender

Comment: yes, I know, But How can make pacman-like animation by shape keys??? I know only the way to use boolean modifier

Comment: try applying the Boolean modifier

Comment: I applyed and I can make open mouth packman, but can't make it back to close the mouth.

Comment: yeah probably it wouldn't notice that blender has something known as shape keys , thats what i told in my first comment , it doesn't support blender , so try rigging it in unity and find some weight pattern that deforms mesh in desired way.